# Modify username in ssh

Tags: ssh

When ssh into my home router, I use the admin credentials provided by my isp. How do I list all users along with their details (group/privilege) and as the superuser how do I modify their (and my) username?

Comment: Check your router manual, it depends on router model.

Comment: Really? I thought its more on the os side ie: openwrt vs tomato. My router is dlink dir-615  running stock firmware based on busybox.

Answer (score 0):

Username is nothing more than two things:

- a record in `/etc/passwd` file
- a record in `/etc/shadow` file (if your system uses it)

When talking about routers, most of them do not use `/etc/shadow`, so to rename a user you have to change it in the file `/etc/passwd` and here you go. Use `sed` for it.

Changing root username doesn't look like a good idea - there could be software with hardcoded root username, for sure.